# ¿Cómo poner un botón en un préstamo sin devolución en php?

Tags: php, mysqli

estoy intentando hacer un ejercicio práctico, la cosa es que hay que poner un botón en los prestamos que no se han devuelto, pero no consigo desarrollar la lógica, o al menos como plantearla, esto es lo que he conseguido hasta ahora, pongo el enunciado.

Debemos crear un programa que muestre en una tabla HTML todos los ejemplares (***signatura del ejemplar***, ***título del libro*** y ***nombre del socio*** que lo ***tiene en préstamo*** en caso de no estar devuelto).
Aparecerá una fila por cada ejemplar y si este tiene un préstamo sin devolución aparecerá a la derecha un botón (“devolver”) para dejar registrada la devolución del
ejemplar a día de hoy.

Los huecos en blanco son donde debería de aparecer el botón  "devolver" que es un simple formulario, pero no se como desarrollarlo para que esté exacto, gracias de antemano.
[image: Estas son las tablas correspondientes]
[image: Imagen con datos mostrados]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ejercicio 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        require_once 'config/conexion.php';

        $link = conecta_bd();
        
        $consulta1 = 
        "select e.eje_signatura,l.lib_titulo,s.soc_nombre,p.pre_devolucion 
        from ejemplares e,libros l,socios s,prestamos p 
        where e.eje_libro = l.lib_isbn 
        AND e.eje_signatura = p.pre_ejemplar AND s.soc_id = p.pre_socio";

        $resultado = mysqli_query($link,$consulta1);

        echo "<table border=1>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>Signatura</th>";
            echo "<th>Titulo</th>";
            echo "<th>Nombre</th>";
            echo "<th>Devueltos</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado)) {
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$fila[0]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$fila[1]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$fila[2]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$fila[3]."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es realizar la comprobación mientras recorres cada fila del array resultado de tu consulta y si este no tiene fecha de devolución imprimes el botón:

```
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado)) {
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$fila[0]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$fila[1]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$fila[2]."</td>";
                if($fila[3]!=NULL){
                     echo "<td>".$fila[3]."</td>";
                }else{
                     echo "<td><form method="POST">";
                     echo "<button type=submit name=devolver value=".$fila[0].">";
                     echo "</form></td>";
                }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
```

Como ves, cuando se cumple que no existe fecha de devolución imprimo el botón. Es importante que en el value le pases un id del libro o del préstamo que lo identifique únicamente.

Y una vez recibas el id del libro o prestamo a devolver solo tienes que hacer un UPDATE en la base de datos y añadirle la fecha.

*La fecha de devolución debería ser predeterminadamente NULL

Comment: oh gracias @BoredGeek y pensar que la lógica era así de simple ! voy a probarlo y comento !

Comment: De nada :) si te falla algo coméntamelo.

Comment: Pues el caso es que me muestra los valores a devolver pero no el botón en la tabla.

Comment: En la base de datos esta puesto como NULL si no hay fecha? Prueba a poner un resultado de la base de datos como NULL

Comment: te lo muestro arriba en la foto, es que no me dejaba añadirla como respuesta, gracias @BoredGeek

Comment: @DavidMilanes Perdona, si que imprime el button pero como no esta dentro de un <td> no te lo muestra. He editado la respuesta a la pregunta. Ahora si te funcionara. Por esa razon cuando inspeccionas elemento marca desbordamiento en los button.

Comment: Vale ahora si va perfecto ! faltaba imprimirle el td como hiciste en el comentario, :D

Comment: Perfecto, Me alegro que ya funcione, recuerda que puedes aceptar la respuesta si te ha servido de ayuda para que otros usuarios vean que la solucion es correcta. Saludos!

Comment: Listo echo ! gracias por la ayuda! toca seguir practicando la lógica. un saludo @BoredGeek